# Displaying different Images with multiple buttons in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image, button, onclick

I'm a newbie to Javascript and I'm trying to put together a program that displays one image at a time, and when a different button is pressed a new image is shown to replace the old one. I'm hoping that you all could help me out with this one!

Here's what I have so far:

```
<html>

<body>

<p>My favorite Beers!</p>

<style type="text/css">
.show{display:block;}
.hide{display:none;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showImg() {
        var obj = document.getElementById('picture1','picture2','picture3','picture4','picture5','picture6','picture7','picture8','picture9','picture10');      
        obj.className = 'show';
    }

</script>

<body>
<img id="picture1" src="lost abbey.png"class="show">
<input type="button" onclick = "showImg()" value= "Lost And Found">

<img id="picture2" src="stone-gtipa-bottle.jpg" class="hide">
<input type="button" onclick = "showImg('stone-gtipa-bottle.jpg')" value= "Green Tea IPA">

<img id="picture3" src="belching beaver.jpg" class="hide">
<input type="button" onclick = "showImg()" value= "Belching Beaver">

<img id="picture4" src="boardwalk_insta.jpg" class="hide">
<input type="button" onclick = "showImg()" value= "Karl Strauss">

<img id="picture5" src="el conquistador epa.jpg" class="hide">
<input type="button" onclick = "showImg()" value= "Mission Brewery">

<img id="Picture6" src="fallbrook.png" class="hide">
<input type="button" onclick = "showImg()" value= "Fallbrook Brewery">

<img id="Picture7" src='gordon biersch golden ale.jpg' class="hide">
<input type="button" onclick = "showImg()" value= "Gordon Biersch">

<img id="Picture8" src="grumpy bear.jpg" class="hide">
<input type="button" onclick = "showImg()" value= "Grizzly Paw">

<img id="Picture10" src="Moderntimes.jpg" class="hide">
<input type="button" onclick = "showImg()" value= "Modern Times">

<img id="Picture9" src="lost-abbey-agave-maria1.png" class="hide">
<input type="button" onclick = "showImg()" value= "Agave Maria">

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You're not that far off, but I think you're making it too hard for yourself.

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a better way (don't predefine all the images and don't set them all to `hide`, but whatever, the following script and HTML will do more or less what you want.

```
<script>
function showImg( id ) {
        // hide previously shown image
        for ( i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
            var obj = document.getElementById( "picture" + i );
            if (obj != null)
                obj.className = 'hide';
        }
        var obj = document.getElementById( "picture" + id );      
        if (obj != null)
            obj.className = 'show';
}
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    .show{display:block;}
    .hide{display:none;}
</style>

<p>My favorite Beers!</p>

<img id="picture1" src="lost abbey.png" title="1" class="show">
<input type="button" onclick="showImg(1);" value="Lost And Found">

<img id="picture2" src="stone-gtipa-bottle.jpg" title="2" class="hide">
<input type="button" onclick="showImg(2);" value="Green Tea IPA">

<img id="picture3" src="belching beaver.jpg" title="3" class="hide">
<input type="button" onclick="showImg(3);" value= "Belching Beaver">

<img id="picture4" src="boardwalk_insta.jpg" title="4" class="hide">
<input type="button" onclick = "showImg(4)" value= "Karl Strauss">

<img id="picture5" src="el conquistador epa.jpg" title="5" class="hide">
<input type="button" onclick = "showImg(5)" value= "Mission Brewery">

<img id="picture6" src="fallbrook.png" class="hide">
<input type="button" onclick = "showImg(6)" value= "Fallbrook Brewery">

<img id="picture7" src='gordon biersch golden ale.jpg' class="hide">
<input type="button" onclick = "showImg(7)" value= "Gordon Biersch">

<img id="picture8" src="grumpy bear.jpg" class="hide">
<input type="button" onclick = "showImg(8)" value= "Grizzly Paw">

<img id="picture10" src="Moderntimes.jpg" class="hide">
<input type="button" onclick = "showImg(10)" value= "Modern Times">

<img id="picture9" src="lost-abbey-agave-maria1.png" class="hide">
<input type="button" onclick = "showImg(9)" value= "Agave Maria">
```

An alternative, would be to have a single `<img>` anchor, and then the buttons would change the `src` of the `<img>` based on what the `<input type="button" onclick="showImg();>"` sends in as `src` rather than a number.
My goal has been to make a solution which is closely based on what you already have.